# partially filled arrays program terminates early runtime

Tags: java, arrays, runtime

Trying to make a program that uses a partially filled array. The beginning of the code deals with getting user input for the array size and getting them to enter a value to be placed in the array. Then I want the values to be sorted as they are entered.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    int userInput;
    int[] userArray;
    int numElements;
    int index;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter number of values in array (5 to 10): ");
    userInput = keyboard.nextInt();

    while (userInput < 5 || userInput > 10)
        {
            System.out.print("Enter number of values in array (5 to 10): ");
            userInput = keyboard.nextInt();
        }

    System.out.println(); //Space, for neatness

    userArray = new int[userInput];

    for (int item: userArray)
        System.out.print(item + " ");

    System.out.print("\nEnter an integer value: ");
    userInput = keyboard.nextInt();


        int numElements = 0;
        int index = 0;
        if (numElements == userArray.length - 1)
            System.out.println("The array is full.");
        else
        {
            while (index < numElements && userArray[index] < userInput)
            {

                if (userArray[index] != 0) //Shift the array to the right, and add value at the current index as to not overwrite values.
                {
                    for (int i = numElements; i > index; i--)
                        userArray[i] = userArray[i - 1];

                    userArray[index] = userInput;
                }

                userArray[index] = userInput;
                index++;
                numElements++;

                System.out.print("Updated array: ");
                for (int item: userArray)
                    System.out.print(item + " ");

                System.out.println("\nEnter an integer value: ");
                userInput = keyboard.nextInt();
            }
        }   
}
```

Having trouble with my output. After I enter a value, the program terminates. For example (I print the empty array on purpose):

```
Enter number of values in array (5 to 10): 5

0 0 0 0 0 
Enter an integer value: 5
```

Sorry for the lack of comments.

Comment: Please paste a complete code.

Answer (score 1):

This part of your statement is always FALSE!

```
index < numElements
```

index and numElements are both 0 initially.  Thus your while loop just skips and is done.

Comment: Thanks that is true, any idea how i can go about moving through the array with a while loop then? I am trying to find the next location for the element to go. This is where the next element is larger than the one I want to add.

Answer (score 0):

try replacing the last part of your code by this :

```
       int numElements = 0;

    while (numElements < userArray.length ) {

       System.out.print("\nEnter an integer value: ");
       userInput = keyboard.nextInt();  
       //insert into the first column
       userArray[0] = userInput;

        // order the table
          for (int i=0 ;i<=(userArray.length-2);i++)
                    for (int j=(userArray.length-1);i < j;j--)
                            if (userArray[j] < userArray[j-1])
                            {
                                    int x=userArray[j-1];
                                    userArray[j-1]=userArray[j];
                                    userArray[j]=x;
                            }
      numElements++;
    }

            System.out.print("Updated array: ");
            for (int item: userArray)
                System.out.print(item + " ");

            System.out.println("\nEnter an integer value: ");
            userInput = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.println("The array is full.");
```